# Finding the minimum dimension of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$'s nontrivial real representations

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-fields

Denote by $\mathbb{F}_q$ the finite field with $q$ elements, and $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ the special linear group in $n$ variables.

What is the minimum dimension of nontrivial real representations of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$?  What about for the general liner group $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$?

Comment: The general linear group admits the determinant homomorphism to ${\mathbb F} _q^{*}\cong {\mathbb Z}/(q-1)$.  The latter admits in turn a non-trivial real representation of dimension $1$ if $q$ is odd, dimension $2$ if $q=2^m$ with $m>1$.

Comment: There is a $\frac{q^n-q}{q-1}$ dimensional representation of $SL_n(\mathbb{F})$ over any field $k$ given by the action of $SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ on the space of $k$-value functions on $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{F}_q^n)$ of total sum zero.  If $k$ is of characteristic zero this is known to be the smallest dimensional non-trivial representation for all but finitely many (explicitly known) pairs $(n,q)$.

Comment: @Nate Can you give me the link that gives the proof of your statement?

Comment: Take a look at "Minimal characters of the finite classical groups" by Tiep and Zalesskii.